# Git submodule gets detached on submodule update

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a submodule which I wish to be on head.  Whenever I

```
git submodule update --recursive
```

on the main repo, I get this output:

```
Submodule path 'my_submodule': checked out '0076552d05a0eed244c7bca8aas224086e65a'
```

and then with git branch in the submodule:

```
* (HEAD detached at 0076552)
  master
```

This is definitely not the behavour I want, and it doesn't happen with other submodules I have - how can I fix this?

Comment: That is the normal behavior

Comment: The more interesting question is, why *doesn't* it happen with other submodules? (I suspect it's because they're already on the right commit hash so that `git submodule update` does not need to yank them to a different one.)

Comment: Ok, thank you - how do I change it so that it stays attached to head when it is updated please?

Comment: adding --remote to the update fixes it, although I would prefer to have this submodule automatically tracking head

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+branch